# How to bulk rename files from windows in linux with accents?

Tags: linux, windows

I've got many files which came from windows zipped file. The files has accents in names like:

"partyku?y no.doc" (this is the string displayed in linux terminal)

How to unpack or maybe rename with correct chars?

**UPDATE:**

Firstly i extract zip in 'win xp'.. result:

garbage in names

Next step, unzip in 'win 7'.. result:

perfect names.

So I downloaded 7z for windows and compressed as 7z and as a zip (both with 7z)

Then put files to linux and extract it with '7z x ..' on files..

7z spits correct names but .zip not.

I was lucky to have an access to 'win 7', what if not? Replacing chars like rody_o suggest?

Comment: And you're sure it's the filenames, and not, e.g., that your terminal font doesn't have good UTF-8 support? The names also look like that, e.g., on desktop or in a file browser window?

Comment: I checked it and it's not only terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Figure out which encoding the filenames are in and use `convmv` to rename them.

Comment: I used it but it told the files are utf8 already and they still wasn't well displayed.

Comment: There is a difference between the encoding of the files' **names** and the encoding of the files' **contents**. Most likely your terminal is UTF-8, so if the filenames aren't correctly displayed, they are not UTF-8. So that means that you should double-check that you have correctly used `convmv`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the real question here is "how do I transfer files using zip without corrupting non-ASCII filenames?".  If this is the real problem that you are trying to solve, try using the "`-UN=UTF8`" command-line option to `zip` when you create the archive.  This will force zip to store filenames using UTF-8, which should preserve non-ASCII characters.

Comment: What if someone else creates zip? 'Someone else' who is limited to mastered only windows zip? Is there any chance to uncompress it on linux AND have good names? :)

Comment: If the zip is created without UTF-8 support enabled, then the filenames will be corrupted when they are stored in the file.  You can't recover them later, as the original name is not stored anywhere.  This is a classic problem with the zip format, see http://linux.die.net/man/1/zip for a more thorough description.  If you are limited to the version of zip that is built into Windows, I recommend sticking to ASCII filenames only.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're sure that *really* is the filename and not some encoding conflict, then you can bulk-rename such files with

```
rename s/REGEX/REPLACEMENT/ *.doc
```

or, a slightly more aesthetic way,

```
rename s,REGEX,REPLACEMENT, *.doc
```

in which case you don't need to escape things like `?`.

`REGEX` and `REPLACEMENT` are regular expressions -- `rename` is basically `sed` for file renaming.

When bulk-renaming with `rename`, it's always a good idea to run `rename` with the `-n` option *before* doing the actual renaming. This option means "dry-run", so just print what *would* be done if the `-n` were removed.

Be sure to read `man rename` and/or `man sed` before experimenting.